# How to get a list of URIs of photos stored in library ?

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic2, cordova-plugins

Is there any possibility using `cordova-plugin-file` or any other plugin compatible with Ionic 2, which allows to get a list of URIs of all photos in the library, also of those saved in iCloud? I want to show a grid of all photos (kind of a custom gallery) using `img src='<PHOTO-URI>'`

Comment: sure.. you can use pretty much any cordova plugin with ionic 2. Check the docs..They have made integration easier.  https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/image-picker/

Comment: I have looked into the plugins you mentioned. I did also try the image-picker, however they dont work well in ios, due to sandboxing. Image-picker does show only the images which are not yet synchronized into the icloud. But I need something simple, a function call which would just return me all the URIs so than I can work with them...